# Using Campbell's formula to find intensity measure $\Theta$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, point-processes, random-measures, stochastic-geometry

**Problem**

Let $X_1, \ldots,X_n \sim K$ i.i.d random variables on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and let
$$
\beta_{n,k} = \{ (x_1,\ldots,x_k) \in \{ X_1, \ldots,X_n\}^k \mid i \neq j, x_i \neq x_j \forall i,j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}\}
$$
be the set of all $k$-tuples from the $n$ random variables with no repetition in both indices and values. Now for $f_n : \mathbb{R}^{d\times k} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable and define the random measure
$$
Z = \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{x \in \beta_{n,k}} \delta_{f_n(x)}
$$
and my goal is now to find the intensity measure $\Theta$ of this i.e. compute $\Theta(A):= E[Z(A)]$ for any $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

**Attempt**

I believe it is possible to show that

$$
E[Z(A)] = \frac{n_{(k)}}{k!} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d\times k}} 1_A(f_n(x)) K^k(dx)
$$
which would also suffice for my purposes. Here $n_{(k)} := n\cdot(n-1)\cdot \ldots\cdot(n-k+1)$. Using Campbell's formula and that $\{ X_1, \ldots,X_n\}^k$ has intensity measure $K^k$ (by independence and identical distribution) , we get that
\begin{align*}
E[Z(A)] &= \frac{1}{k!}E\bigg[\sum_{x \in \beta_{n,k}} \delta_{f_n(x)}(A)\bigg] \\
& = \frac{1}{k!}E\bigg[\sum_{x \in \{ X_1, \ldots,X_n\}^k} 1_{\beta_{n,k}}(x) 1_A(f_n(x))\bigg] \\
&= \frac{1}{k!} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d\times k}} \sum_{x \in \{ X_1, \ldots,X_n\}^k} 1_{\beta_{n,k}}(x) 1_A(f_n(x)) K^k(dx),
\end{align*}
but this is not quite we we wanted. We need to get rid of $1_{\beta_{n,k}}(x)$ and the sum, and somehow replace with this combinatorical factor $n_{(k)}$. However I am not quite sure how this happens.

*Can anyone help me?*

Answer (score 1):

Instead of considering $\beta_{n,k}$, whose number of elements may vary with $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$, consider a fixed set of $k$-tuples
$$
\alpha_{n,k} = \{(x_1, \dotsc, x_k) \in \{X_1, \dotsc, X_n\}^k \, | \, i \neq j \text{ for all } i,j\} ,
$$
which always has $(n)_k$ elements, and put the "untiedness" condition $x_i \neq x_j$ in each summand: With
$$
\gamma = \{(x_1, \dotsc, x_k) \in \{X_1, \dotsc, X_n\}^k \, | \, x_i \neq x_j \text{ for all } i,j\} ,
$$
we have
$$
Z(A) = \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{x \in \alpha_{n,k}} 1_A(f_n(x)) \, 1_\gamma(x) .
$$
Linearity of expectation reveals that your answer should actually be
$$
\frac{(n)_k}{k!} P(f_n(X) \in A, X \in \gamma)
$$
with $X = (X_1, \dotsc, X_k)$, say. The integral you had expected was $P(f_n(X) \in A)$. These would be equal if $K$ had no atom (point with positive probability), but needn't be in general. If $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ are Bernoulli with probability $1/2$, then $Z$ would be a good name for the random measure when $k > 2$, because $Z$ would be zero.

Comment: Could you expand a little bit on "Linearity of expectation reveals that your answer should actually be" part of your answer. A priori the sum i.e. $\alpha_{n,k}$ is stochastic but I guess we can move the randomness to $f_n()$ by instead summing over pairwise different indices. However I am still a bit unsure how to argue precisely for this.

Comment: Rewrite the sum over $x \in \alpha_{n,k}$: Sum over tuples $(i_1, \dotsc, i_k)$ of distinct integers, and write the summand as $1_A(f_n(X_{i_1}, \dotsc, X_{i_k}) \, 1_\gamma(X_{i_1}, \dotsc, X_{i_k})$. Then the sum is over a deterministic set of indices, and the expectation of one term is the probability written above.